# Is there a way to save your COD mobile account

Tags: cod-black-ops-zombies-mobile

Can you save your COD mobile account like Supercell ID or something like that.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (I don't know much about how the mobile version works) what exactly are you looking to "save"?

Comment: My account progress between devices, I play on android btw.